# Neural Networks (SRCNN)

Tags: matlab

I have a problem in applying Super-Resolution Convolutional Neural Networks (SRCNN). In SRCNN code, the 'Readme.txt' file tells

1) Place the "SRCNN" folder into "($Caffe_Dir)/examples/"

2) Open MATLAB and direct to ($Caffe_Dir)/example/SRCNN, run "generate_train.m" and "generate_test.m" to generate training and test data.

3)To train our SRCNN, run ./build/tools/caffe train --solver examples/SRCNN/SRCNN_solver.prototxt

4) After training, you can extract parameters from the caffe model and save them in the format that can
 be used in our test package (SRCNN_v1). To do this, you need to
 install mat-caffe first, then open MATLAB and direct to ($Caffe_Dir)
 and run "saveFilters.m". The "($Caffe_Dir)/examples/SRCNN/x3.mat" will
 be there for you.

In number 3, I don't know how to run prototxt file in Matlab. So there is anyone to help me running prototxt file in Maytlab? I want some example code to run prototxt file in Matlab. Thank you for reading.

Comment: there is no number 3 in the post. I can barely see 3 sentences. [edit] for clarification

Comment: Yes. I mean this part:run ./build/tools/caffe train --solver examples/SRCNN/SRCNN_solver.prototxt

Comment: have you tried `!run ./build/tools/caffe train --solver examples/SRCNN/SRCNN_solver.prototxt`

Comment: should I run id in cmd? give me error: it is not recognized as an external and internal command.

Comment: In cmd, without the `!`, in MATLAB, as I said

Comment: I installed caffe on my system but I can not call caffe train from cmd. I do not why?